# how to pass value between classes -

Tags: ios, swift

I have a the following code which is cocoa touch class, which draws a simple pie chart, and with the value CGFloat I can adjust the image to show the correct amount of Pie.

how can i pass a value for example from a slider in the main view controler.swift to it, instead of having it fixed?

```
    public class PieChart : NSObject {



    public class func drawCanvas1(ratio ratio: CGFloat = 0.75) {

        //// Variable Declarations
        let expression: CGFloat = 90 + ratio * 360


        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: -0, width: 112, height: 112))
        UIColor.blackColor().setFill()
        ovalPath.fill()



        let oval2Rect = CGRect(x: 4, y: 4, width: 104, height: 104)
        let oval2Path = UIBezierPath()
        oval2Path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: oval2Rect.midX, y: oval2Rect.midY), radius: oval2Rect.width / 2, startAngle: -expression * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, endAngle: -90 * CGFloat(M_PI)/180, clockwise: true)
        oval2Path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: oval2Rect.midX, y: oval2Rect.midY))
        oval2Path.closePath()

        UIColor.redColor().setFill()
        oval2Path.fill()
    }
}
```

and this is my ViewController.swift

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!


    @IBAction func sliderMoved(sender: UISlider) {

        let mySliderValue = sliderValue.value
```

// this is where I'm stuck ->

```
        drawCanvas1 = Float(mySliderValue)


}
```

EDIT : Added code from where Piechart is Initialised

```
import UIKit


@IBDesignable


class PCView: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

        PieChart.drawCanvas1()

    }

}
```

Comment: You need a reference to `PieChart` in `ViewController`. How and where is `PieChart` initialized?

Comment: ok - so i would reference PieChat like this? var sliderUpdate = PieChart!  ?

Comment: added code from where PieChart is initialised -

Comment: You cannot use `drawCanvas1` as a class method. You need to move the code into `drawRect` of `PCView`. In `PCView` declare a property `ratio`. Then you need also a reference of `PCView` in  `ViewController`. To change the value set the property `ratio` and call `setNeedsDisplay()` on`PCView` . How and where is `PCView` initialized?

Comment: Got it -starting to understand now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a delegate pattern to pass data between the `UIView` and `ViewController` using two protocols.

```
protocol IsChart {
  var delegate: ChartDelegate? { get set }
  var ratio: CGFloat { get set }
}

protocol ChartDelegate: class { 
  var pcView: PCView! { get }
}
```

The `PCView` would conform to `IsChart` and the `ViewController` would conform to `ChartDelegate`. Just make sure that when you initialize the `PCView` in the `ViewController` you set its `delegate` property to `self` (The `ViewController`) and you add the initialized `PCView` as the `pcView` property of the `ViewController`. In the `@IBAction` for the `UISlider` you need to set the `pcView`s `ratio` property to `slider.value` and then run `pcView.setNeedsDisplay()`.

Notes:

1. The ratio property would be passed to `drawCanvas1`.
2. you can read more about implementing the delegate pattern and protocols here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

If you have any questions please ask :D.

Comment: You are correct @vadian . I have edited it accordingly. But it should be noted, the values must be set now. If they are it will crash at runtime.

Comment: A non-optional variable must have a default value by definition. The code won't compile otherwise. That's the benefit of the strong type system.

Comment: Could it use implicitly unwrapped optionals and set the values and initialize the pcview  in viewDidLoad? @vadian

Comment: Right, as `pcView` is an implicitly unwrapped `IBOutlet` it must be declared as `var pcView: PCView! { get }` but only with the getter. `ChartDelegate` must be optional (`?`) and `ratio`as scalar type non-optional because there is always a ratio.

Comment: Edited accordingly! Thanks for the help @vadian